# Java, números aleatórios (sem repetição)

Tags: java

Tenho uma dúvida em gerar números sem repetição.

Já consigo gerar numeros aleatórios de 1 a 8 que é o meu objectivo. O senão é que gera números repetidos (duplicados, triplicados ou até mais). No meu programa não pode haver nenhum número repetido. Meu código até agora:

```
for (int k = 1; k < (gameBtn.length / 2) + 1; k++)    // 1 até 8
        {
            int z= 8 + (int)(Math.random() * (1 - 8));   // Máximo 8, mínimo 1
            gameList.add(z);    // Imprime os números de 1 a 8, podendo sair repetidos
        }
```

Ou seja quero fazer um `if (numeros_anteriores_que_sairam != novo numero)`. Se confirma, imprime `gameList.add(z)`, senão não imprime o número que saiu, (ou elimina números iguais) ou faz outra coisa qualquer sem imprimir o número. Todos os números tem de ser diferentes!

Comment: `(gameBtn.length / 2) + 1` é 8?

Comment: gameBtn.lenght é 16 , logo 16/2=8, se soma um fica 9,

Comment: fiz k=1 até 9, mas podia ter feito k=0 até 8

Comment: Você quer de 1 a 8, de 0 a 8 ou de 1 a 9? De qualquer forma, acho que a minha resposta serve, nem que seja para acrescentar um 0 ou um 9 nela.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente isso:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Aleatorio8 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        Collections.shuffle(lista);
        System.out.println(lista);
    }
}
```

No seu código acho que ficaria assim:

```
gameList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
Collections.shuffle(gameList);
```

Ou talvez assim:

```
List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
Collections.shuffle(lista);
gameList.addAll(lista);
```

Comment: Tá a funcionar tal como queria sem repetição! , agora só tenho que implementar isso no meu codigo acima.

Comment: @insyspower Se a resposta lhe servir, não esqueça de marcá-la como aceita. Caso contrário, vamos conversar para solucionar o seu problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu tudo na perfeição, Resposta aceite.  Tenho uma nova duvida, tenho um botão (JButton) nome "baralhar" que já está implementado, Eu queria fazer o seguinte: quando acionado esse botão, ela baralha os numeros tal e qual acima descrito. Sem que seja necessário reiniciar a aplicação.

Comment: @insyspower Poste uma nova pergunta com isso daí, incluindo o código que você usa no botão.

Answer (score 0):

Este é método **padrão** para gerar números aleatórios em Java:

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Returns a pseudo-random number between min and max, inclusive.
 * The difference between min and max can be at most
 * <code>Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1</code>.
 *
 * @param min Minimum value
 * @param max Maximum value.  Must be greater than min.
 * @return Integer between min and max, inclusive.
 * @see java.util.Random#nextInt(int)
 */
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {


    Random rand = new Random();

    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Veja [the relevant JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-).  Na prática, a classe [java.util.Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) é muita das vezes substituída por [java.lang.Math.random()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random--).