# Java - botões números aleatórios

Tags: java

Tenho uma nova duvida (que é continuação da [minha questão anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58928/132)). Tenho um botão (`JButton`) com onome "baralhar" que já está implementado. Eu queria fazer o seguinte: quando acionado esse botão, ela baralha os números tal e qual acima descrito. Sem que seja necessário reiniciar a aplicação.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

        if (baralharBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            //setArrayListText();
            List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
            Collections.shuffle(lista);
            gameList.addAll(lista);
        }
}
```

O problema é: Quando acionado o botão baralhar, os números mantém as mesmas posições tal como quando iniciei a aplicação, mas eu queria que baralha-se de novo e tal como descrito [na pergunta de números aleatórios anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58928/132). Queria manter a grelha 4x4 que contém os 16 `JButton`s igual. A única diferença é que no botão baralhar, quando acionado, gera novos números aleatórios. (e elimina ou sobrepõe os números que estavam anteriormente).

Desculpe lá voce toda a razão não postei o código todo porque pensei que iria dificultar.
Esse seu techo está dando erros. Por isso postei o codigo completo para ser mais facil.

Tou a utilizar o notepadd++.

Codigo completo com imports:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.applet.Applet;

    public class MemoryGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener

{

    private JCheckBox check1,check2,check3;
    Font f; 
    TextField msg1, msg2, password,t;
    CheckboxGroup cbg;
    Checkbox courier, timesRoman, helvetica;
    String s;
    Label mostra;           
    public int delay = 1000; //1000 milliseconds

    public void Contador()
    {
        ActionListener counter = new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                tempo++;
                TempoScore.setText("Tempo: " + tempo);
            }
        };
        new Timer(delay, counter).start();
    }

    public void updateHitMiss() 
    {
        HitScore.setText("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore.setText("Falhou: " + Miss);
        PontosScore.setText("Pontos: " + Pontos);
    }

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Jogo da Memoria");
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500; // pixels
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500; // pixels
    private JButton exitBtn, baralharBtn, solveBtn, restartBtn, maximoBtn, definicoesBtn;
    ImageIcon ButtonIcon = createImageIcon("card1.png");
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
    private ArrayList<Integer> gameList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    private int Hit, Miss, Pontos, Maximo;
    public int tempo = 0;   
    private int counter = 0;
    private int[] btnID = new int[2];
    private int[] btnValue = new int[2];
    private JLabel HitScore, MissScore, TempoScore, PontosScore, MaximoScore;
    private JPanel gamePnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel scorePnl = new JPanel();

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) 
    {
        java.net.URL imgURL = MemoryGame.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) 
        {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } 
        else  return null;
    }

    public MemoryGame()
    {
        createGUI();
        createJPanels();
        setArrayListText();
        window.setTitle("Jogo da Memoria");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setVisible(true);
        Contador();
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
            gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        HitScore = new JLabel("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore = new JLabel("Falhou: " + Miss);
        TempoScore = new JLabel("Tempo: " + tempo);
        PontosScore = new JLabel("Pontos: " + Pontos);  
        exitBtn = new JButton("Sair");
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
        baralharBtn = new JButton("Baralhar");
        baralharBtn.addActionListener(this);
        solveBtn = new JButton("Resolver");
        solveBtn.addActionListener(this);
        restartBtn = new JButton("Recomecar");
        restartBtn.addActionListener(this);
        maximoBtn = new JButton("Pontuacoes");
        maximoBtn.addActionListener(this);
        definicoesBtn = new JButton("Definicoes");
        definicoesBtn.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void createJPanels()
    {
        gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
        }
        buttonPnl.add(baralharBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(exitBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(solveBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(restartBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(maximoBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(definicoesBtn);
        buttonPnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        scorePnl.add(HitScore);
        scorePnl.add(MissScore);
        scorePnl.add(TempoScore);
        scorePnl.add(PontosScore);
        scorePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        window.add(scorePnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(gamePnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void setArrayListText()
    { 
        List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
        Collections.shuffle(lista);
        gameList.addAll(lista);
    }

    public boolean sameValues()
    {
        if (btnValue[0] == btnValue[1])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void pass() 
    {
        s = "123";
        msg1 = new TextField("Digite a password:"); msg1.setEditable(false);
        password = new TextField(12); password.setEchoCharacter('*');
        msg2 = new TextField(30); msg2.setEditable(false);
        add(msg1); add(password); add(msg2);
    }
    /*
    public boolean action(Event e, Object o) 
    {
        if (e.target instanceof TextField)
        if (e.target ==password)
        if (e.arg.equals(s)) msg2.setText("Acesso permitido");
        else msg2.setText("Password invalida.");
        return true;
    } */
    /*
    class EscutaJanela extends WindowAdapter
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
        setVisible(true);
        dispose();
    }
    */

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
            if (exitBtn == e.getSource())
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if (baralharBtn == e.getSource())
            {
                //setArrayListText();

                List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
                Collections.shuffle(lista);
                //gameList.addAll(lista);
                /*for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                {
                    gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
                    gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
                }*/
                for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                {
                    //gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);                  
                    //gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);
                    gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.addAll(lista));
                }
            }

            if (solveBtn == e.getSource())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                {
                    gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);                  
                    gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);
                    gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));       
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
            {           
                if (gameBtn[i] == e.getSource())
                {
                    gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));
                    gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
                    counter++;

                    if(Hit==7)
                    {
                        if (counter == 2)
                        {
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(false);
                            Hit = Hit +1;
                            Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                        }                   
                    }

                    if(Hit==8)
                    {  
                        int PontuacaoMax=0;
                        PontuacaoMax=Pontos;
                        window = new JFrame(" FIM DO JOGO ");           
                        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("\n PARABENS FINALIZOU O JOGO ! TOTAL DE PONTOS: "+PontuacaoMax);    
                        int[] anArray;
                        int w=0;
                        anArray = new int[20];
                        anArray[w] = PontuacaoMax;
                        System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                        w++;
                        window.add("Center", label3);               
                        window.show();                      
                        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("fogo.jpg");                  
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
                        window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        window.pack();  
                        window.setVisible(true); 
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);

                        //AudioClip audio = Applet.newAudioClip(cl.getResource("bottle-open.wav"));
                        //audio.play();                 
                    }

                    if (counter == 3)
                    {               
                        if (sameValues())
                        {
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);
                            Hit = Hit +1;
                            Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(true);
                            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setText("");
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(true);
                            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setText("");
                            Miss = Miss +1;
                            Pontos = Pontos - 5;                       
                        }
                        counter = 1; 
                    }
                    /*if (Pontos <= 0)
                    {
                        Pontos=0;
                    } */
                    if (counter == 1) // se carregar 1º botão
                    {
                        btnID[0] = i;
                        btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
                    }
                    if (counter == 2) // se carregar 2º botão
                    {
                        btnID[1] = i;
                        btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (restartBtn == e.getSource()) // apaga a grelha
            { 
                Hit=0;
                Miss=0;
                tempo=-1;
                Pontos=0;
                for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                {
                    gameBtn[i].setText("");
                    gameBtn[i].setEnabled(true);
                    gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);    
                }
            }  

            if (maximoBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra melhor pontucao
            {
                window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Melhores Pontuacoes:"); 
                int Max=0,PontuacaoMax=0;           

                //private static int maxValue(char[] chars) 
                //{
                    //int  = chars[0]; 
                    /*
                    int[] anArray;
                    anArray = new int[20];
                    for (int w = 0; w < anArray.length; w++) 
                    {
                        if (anArray[w]>= Max) 
                        {
                            Max = anArray[w];
                            JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+Max);
                            window.add("Center", label2);
                        }
                    }

                    System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                    JLabel label5 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao: " +PontuacaoMax );
                    window.add("Center", label5); */
                    //return Pontos;
                //}
                /*
                anArray[w]=0;
                int w;
                for(w=0;w<20;w++)
                {
                    if (anArray[w]>=PontuacaoMax)
                    {
                        PontuacaoMax=anArray[w];
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax);
                        window.add("Center", label2);
                    }
                } 
                */ 
                if (Pontos >= PontuacaoMax)
                {
                    PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax); 
                    //Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
                    //v.add(PontuacaoMax);System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                    window.add("Center", label2);
                }
                if (Pontos < PontuacaoMax)
                {
                    PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: 0");         
                    window.add("Center", label2);
                }    

                window.show();                      
                ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("trofeu.jpg");           
                JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
                window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                window.pack();  
                window.setVisible(true); 
            }

            if (definicoesBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra melhor pontucao
            { /*
                window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Password:");
                window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
                // pass(); 
                s = "123";
                msg1 = new TextField("Digite a password:"); 
                msg1.setEditable(false);
                password = new TextField(12); 
                password.setEchoCharacter('*');
                msg2 = new TextField(30); 
                msg2.setEditable(false);
                add(msg1); 
                add(password); 
                add(msg2); 

                window.resize(300,300);
                window.show();                      
                window.pack();  
                window.setVisible(true);    
                //action(e,o);  */      

                definicoesBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {    
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
                    {    
                        window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Definicoes:");              
                        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Escolha Nivel Dificuldade:");           
                        window.add("West", label3);                                     
                        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("definicoes.jpg");
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
                        window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
                        JRadioButton aRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Facil ");
                        JRadioButton bRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Medio ");
                        JRadioButton cRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Dificil ");

                        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() 
                        {
                              public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changEvent) 
                              {
                                    AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton)changEvent.getSource();
                                    ButtonModel aModel = aButton.getModel();
                                    boolean armed = aModel.isArmed();
                                    boolean pressed = aModel.isPressed();
                                    boolean selected = aModel.isSelected();

                                    aRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                        {                           
                                            gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
                                            //System.out.println("4x4");
                                        }
                                    });
                                    bRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                        {                                       
                                            JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[18];

                                             for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                            {
                                                gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
                                                gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
                                            } 

                                            gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6)); /*
                                            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                            {
                                                gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
                                            }           */                                                  
                                        }
                                    });
                                    cRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                                    {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                        {                                                                                   
                                            gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));                                                
                                        }
                                    });
                               }
                        };
                        panel.add(aRadioButton);
                        group.add(aRadioButton);
                        panel.add(bRadioButton);
                        group.add(bRadioButton);
                        panel.add(cRadioButton);
                        group.add(cRadioButton);
                        aRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                        bRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                        cRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                        window.add(panel);                      
                        window.pack();  
                        window.setVisible(true); 
                    }    
                });             
            }
        updateHitMiss();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {      
        new MemoryGame();
    }
}
```

Comment: possível duplicata de [Java, números aleatórios (sem repetição)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58928/java-n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios-sem-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: Acho que seria pertinente você colocar o código aonde você cria os `JButton`s e a lista `gameList`. Se possível, coloque a classe inteira, pois só com este trecho, não dá para saber como você gerencia os seus botões e nem porque os números mantêm a mesma posição de quando você inicia a aplicação.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Não é duplicata. A pergunta anterior é sobre a geração dos números aleatórios. Esta daqui é sobre como colocá-los em `JButton`s.

Comment: Poste logo o código completo da classe (na pergunta!), senão fica difícil entender o que você está fazendo. Ao postar o código completo você nos ajuda a te ajudar, pois assim poderemos compilar e testá-lo com a certeza de que não há nada importante faltando.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que o que você quer é algo mais ou menos assim. Não tenho como ter certeza porque **você não deu o código completo, daí fica difícil de te ajudar!**

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class JogoDaMemoria extends JFrame {
    private int counter;
    private JButton baralharBtn;
    private JButton solveBtn;
    private int[] btnID = new int[16];
    private int[] btnValue = new int[16];
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];

    private List<Integer> gameList;

    public void createGUI() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++) {
            int idx = i;
            gameBtn[i] = new JButton(/*ButtonIcon*/);
            gameBtn[i].addActionListener(e -> clicou(idx));
        }

        baralharBtn = new JButton("Baralhar");
        baralharBtn.addActionListener(e -> baralhar());

        solveBtn = new JButton("Solucionar");
        solveBtn.addActionListener(e -> solucionar());
    }

    private void baralhar() {
        gameList = Arrays.asList(8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
        Collections.shuffle(gameList);
    }

    private void solucionar() {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++) {
            gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
            gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);
            gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void clicou(int i) {
        gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));
        gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1) // se carregar 1º botão
        {
            btnID[0] = i;
            btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
        }
        if (counter == 2) // se carregar 2º botão
        {
            btnID[1] = i;
            btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
            //outra parte do codigo, pode ser que ajude
            if (counter == 1) // se carregar 1º botão
            {
                btnID[0] = i;
                btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
            }
            if (counter == 2) // se carregar 2º botão
            {
                btnID[1] = i;
                btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

O que observar deste código:

- O seu problema é que você estava adicionando os números embaralhados na lista, ao invés de ela ser a própria lista. Como resultado, a lista sempre crescia, mas as primeiras 16 posições permaneciam as mesmas.
- Não coloque todos os botões no mesmo `ActionListener`, isso é uma péssima prática de programação que infelizmente é muito difundida e deve ser combatida. Em especial colocar o seu `JFrame` implementando `ActionListener` também é uma má prática de programação.

**E agora o puxão de orelha:**

Após três perguntas, tenho aqui acima um código pela metade que talvez resolva o seu problema. Se você já tivesse postado um código **completo** e **compilável** desde o início, e não apenas pequenos trechos cheios de variáveis com propósito e significado desconhecido para quem está respondendo, você teria conseguido uma boa resposta em poucos minutos.

Isso acontece porque para respondermos a sua pergunta, nós usamos o compilador para compilar programas, mas o compilador não aceita código incompleto. Não tem como sabermos o que acontece no seu programa se ele referencia um monte de classes e variáveis que não estão no código que você forneceu.

Além disso, exigir que os demais usuários tenham que adivinhar o que há no resto do seu código para poder te ajudar, só vai servir para conseguir pouca ajuda e muitos votos negativos e de fechamento.

**Então da próxima vez, poste um código completo e compilável, incluindo os imports!**

Comment: +1 para o puxão de orelha, isso vale para todos, afinal de contas, a maioria de nós esta no trabalho e dispensamos alguns minutos para ajudar um colega, então precisa haver colaboração de quem realmente necessita de ajuda.